# Error in db2hpu procedure call

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

Is there a solution to this problem in db2hpu call:

> SQL0443N  Routine "DB2INST1.DB2HPU" (specific name "SQL160823160100917") has
>   returned an error SQLSTATE with diagnostic text "Cannot Connect: rc =
>   0x25a7dd".  SQLSTATE=38107

Thanks a lot

Comment: What's in `db2diag.log` at the time of error?

Comment: db2diag erro:  `2016-08-24-08.43.54.140799+000 I206912E1075          LEVEL: Error
PID     : 530                  TID : 140252475811584 PROC : db2sysc 0
INSTANCE: db2inst1             NODE : 000            DB   : TESTDB2
APPHDL  : 0-98                 APPID: *LOCAL.db2inst1.160824084222
AUTHID  : DB2INST1             HOSTNAME: db2inst1
EDUID   : 87                   EDUNAME: db2agent (TESTDB2) 0
FUNCTION: DB2 UDB, routine_infrastructure, sqlerInvokeFencedRoutine, probe:99
MESSAGE : ZRC=0xFFFFFB95=-1131
 SQL1131N  A stored procedure process has been terminated abnormally.`

Comment: `DATA #1 : SQLCA, PD_DB2_TYPE_SQLCA, 136 bytes
 sqlcaid : SQLCA     sqlcabc: 136   sqlcode: -1131   sqlerrml: 36
 sqlerrmc: -2097151957 * * * *  SEMAPHORE WAIT
 sqlerrp : SQLJCMN
 sqlerrd : (1) 0x8136001C      (2) 0x0000001C      (3) 0x00000000
           (4) 0x00000000      (5) 0x00000000      (6) 0x00000000
 sqlwarn : (1)      (2)      (3)      (4)        (5)       (6)
           (7)      (8)      (9)      (10)        (11)
 sqlstate:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Cannot Connect: rc = ..." error is coming from HPU stored procedure, not DB2 itself.
It may be raised if the db2hpudm deamon is not able to start.

Verify that the HPU was correctly installed and that you have no warnings or error in the installation trace files under : 
[INSTALLDIR]/install/trace_error_install
[INSTALLDIR]/install/trace_warning_install